# How can I resolve the access violation exception when opening a USD file using my custom-built USD C++ library?

Tags: exception, dll, build, compiler-errors, usd

I am currently trying to use the USD C++ library in a custom C++ project on Windows 11, using Visual Studio 2019.

From the USD GitHub repo [text](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD), I downloaded the latest source code release and built the lib using the `build_usd.py` located in the `build_scripts/` directory. I built the libary with a few flags to avoid building unnecessary features (I basically only kept Alembic and HDF5 flags because I am planning to use the Alembic library in the same project).

However, once the library is added to my project, I run this block of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pxr/pxr.h>
#include <pxr/usd/usd/stage.h>

int main() {
    std::string a("C:\\Users\\h.debouard\\Desktop\\Kitchen_set\\Kitchen_set.usd");
    pxr::UsdStageRefPtr stage = pxr::UsdStage::Open(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following thrown exception :
`Exception thrown at 0x00007FF810001190 (vcruntime140.dll) in alembicwrapper.exe : 0xC0000005 : Access violation reading location 0x00000219EF1A0000`.

No matter how many extra libraries I try to add or build options I change, I still encounter this error and I haven't been able to find the answer on the issue section of the GitHub page.

What am I doing wrong here ? Is this an issue that could be related to the compiler ?

The first problem for me is that I have to include several directories to the project, and not only the USD `include/` directory from the `build/` folder, otherwise I get errors telling me some header files from the library can't be located.

What bugs me is that those extra directories are located in the USD `include/` directory itself, the paths indicated in some of the source files in the `#include <some-source-lib.h>` line are not correct, which is why I need to add those.

I also need to link against several libraries that are also located in the `build/lib` and `build/bin` dirs in order to avoid some `LNK2019` errors.

My goal here is just to open a USD file in order to check if the lib is working correctly. I know my USD file is correct since it is an official example from the USD website.